# How can I get my input validation to work so anything outside range -1 - 100 will display the error message?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Defining the constants for min and max range
    final int minValue = -1;
    final int maxValue = 100;
    String message = "Welcome to Simple Gradebook!";

    promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);

    // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
    int score = 0;
    boolean doneYet = false;

    do {
        // Input Validation
        if (score < minValue || score > maxValue) {
            System.err.printf(
                    "Invalid value. The acceptable range is" + " between %d and %d\n" + "Please try again\n",
                    minValue, maxValue);
            score = promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);
        } else {
            doneYet = true;
        }
    } while (doneYet == false);
}

public static int promptForInt(String message, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
    int sum = 0;
    int numStudents = 0;
    int score = 0;

    System.out.println(message);

    // Creating the sentinel loop
    do {
        System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d" + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        score = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());

        if (score != -1) {
            sum += score;
            numStudents += 1;
        }

    } while (score != -1);
    double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;

    // Passing method to this method to convert grade to letter
    convertToLetter(avgScore);
    System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore + " which equates to a " + avgScore);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get my input validation to work so anything outside range -1 - 100 will display the error message? I want to use the "do-while" loop and thought I was doing it all correctly. If a user enters a value outside the defined range, it should display the error message and prompt again for the score. What am I missing?

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash here is a separate post.

Comment: I hope the answer meets your validation requirements. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash... is it possible to prompt the user again after the error message? So if the score for student one was already entered and the user entered an invalid number for the second score. It would display the error message then prompt the user for the second score again instead of stating the loop for score over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A good place to do the validation is inside the method, `promptForInt`.
2. Since there is no use of the value returned from method, `promptForInt`, it's better to declare it as `void`.
3. Do not instantiate the `Scanner` object inside the loop.

The following code has incorporated all these comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Defining the constants for min and max range
        final int minValue = -1;
        final int maxValue = 100;
        String message = "Welcome to Simple Gradebook!";

        promptForInt(message, minValue, maxValue);
    }

    public static void promptForInt(String message, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        // Declaring variables for the loop & the sentinel variable
        int sum = 0;
        int numStudents = 0;
        int score = 0;
        boolean valid;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(message);

        // Loop to continue getting score for students until -1 is entered to quit
        do {
            System.out.printf("Enter the score for student #%d" + "(or -1 to quit): ", numStudents);
            // Loop for getting input of score for the current student
            do {
                valid = true;
                score = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
                // Input Validation
                if (score < minValue || score > maxValue) {
                    System.err.printf(
                            "Invalid value. The acceptable range is" + " between %d and %d\n" + "Please try again\n",
                            minValue, maxValue);
                    valid = false;
                }
            } while (!valid);

            if (score != -1) {
                sum += score;
                numStudents += 1;
            }

        } while (score != -1);

        double avgScore = (double) sum / numStudents;

        // Passing method to this method to convert grade to letter
        convertToLetter(avgScore);
        System.out.println("The average score is: " + avgScore + " which equates to a " + convertToLetter(avgScore));
    }

    public static char convertToLetter(double avg) {
        char gradeLetter;
        // Identifying the ranges for the grade letter
        if (avg >= 90) {
            gradeLetter = 'A';
        } else if (avg >= 80) {
            gradeLetter = 'B';
        } else if (avg >= 70) {
            gradeLetter = 'C';
        } else if (avg >= 60) {
            gradeLetter = 'D';
        } else {
            gradeLetter = 'F';
        }
        return gradeLetter;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to Simple Gradebook!
Enter the score for student #0(or -1 to quit): -2
Invalid value. The acceptable range is between -1 and 100
Please try again
-4
Invalid value. The acceptable range is between -1 and 100
Please try again
45
Enter the score for student #1(or -1 to quit): 50
Enter the score for student #2(or -1 to quit): -1
The average score is: 47.5 which equates to a F
```

Comment: I see... you did a nested do-while loop. Thank you for you help!

Comment: is it possible to prompt the user again after the error message?  So if the score for student one was already entered and the user entered an invalid number for the second score. It would display the error message then prompt the user for the second score again

Comment: @Brown - This is how it is working. Test it once again and feel free to comment in case you need any further support.